# How can I insert into Yahoo! Pipes feed titles?

Tags: regex, yahoo-pipes

This query concerns Yahoo Pipes only.

I want to search for a series of characters in a feed title, and when I've found it, I want to insert some text.  Yahoo Pipe's regex module allows you to search and replace, but I don't want to search and replace, only search and insert.  Does anybody know whether this is possible?

Comment: What does this have to do with Perl?

Comment: Removed `perl` tag because I cannot see any connection to Perl.

Comment: Inserting is replacing, you're just replacing nothing with something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use the regex module to insert some text. Some examples:

### Simple insert

If your title is *AAACCC* and you want to insert *BBB* to get *AAABBBCCC*,

replace

> AC

with

> ABBBC

### Simple append

If your title is *AAACCC* and you want to append *BBB* to get *AAACCCBBB*,

replace

> $

with

> BBB

### Insert with capturing groups

For more complicated cases you can use capturing groups. For example suppose your title consists of some letters at the beginning and some digits at the end, like *Oct2009*. And you want to seperate the letters and numbers with a slash, like *Oct - 2009*

replace

> ([a-zA-Z]+)([0-9]+)

with

> $1 - $2

Where $1 is the match of the first pair of brackets () and $2 is the match of the second pair of brackets ().

### Insert other feed attributes

Suppose your feed items have an attribute author and you want to append *by Authorname* to the title of your feed,

replace

> $

with

> by ${author}

For an item with an attribute title=*Interesting Text* and author=*John Doe* this will result in title=*Interesting Text by John Doe*